# How to get return value from cordova.exec()

Tags: android, cordova, adt

Hello I am very confusing that how to get the return type from `cordova.exec`. Every time it return a undefined value.

My Cordova Version is : 3.5.0 (latest)

My objective is calling a Java class from html file. The java class process some data like get data from SOAP webservice and Java class return some data to html/js and with the value I can plot the data in html file with help of Javascript/Jquery.

Here is my scripts.
From **Sample.html** I am sending a value (`var value = SampleJavaClass.echo("Arg frm login");`) to the **samplejavaclass.js** and the js call native Java Class and add a message return the actual message. Then I want to get data in **Sample.html** file and do some task.

#### SampleJavaClass.java.

I want to process some data in this class. eg. Call soap webservice

```
public class SampleJavaClass extends CordovaPlugin {

    public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
        super.initialize(cordova, webView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args,
            final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

        try {
            if (action.equals("echo")) {
                final String message = args.getString(0);
                cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        String retMsg = "SUCCESS " + message;
                        callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(Status.OK, retMsg));
                    }
                });
            }
            return true;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(
                    PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION));
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void echo(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        if (message != null && message.length() > 0) {
            //callbackContext.success("SUCCESS " + message);
            String retMsg = "SUCCESS " + message;
            callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(Status.OK, retMsg));
        } else {
            callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
        }
    }
}
```

#### simplejavaclass.js

```
function SampleJavaClass() {
}

function nativePluginResultHandler(result) {
    alert("SUCCESS: \r\n" + result);
}

function nativePluginErrorHandler(error) {
    alert("ERROR: \r\n" + error);
}

SampleJavaClass.echo = function(arg) {
//  var failureCallback = function() {
//      console.log("Not able to retrive ");
//  };

    return cordova.exec(nativePluginResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler,
            "SampleJavaClass", "echo", [ arg ]);
};
```

#### Sample.html

```
var value = SampleJavaClass.echo("Arg frm login");
alert("Return Value in login  :: " + value);
```

In **simplejavaclass.js** is printing the alert. It means it executing successfully. But in **Sample.html** the value shows in alert is **undefined**.

Please tell me a way out if I am doing something wrong.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In sample.html, you are getting the return value of echo function. This means, your "value" actually equals the return value of cordova.exec method, not the success callback's response, hence your "value" variable is undefined.

Comment: But I am calling the success callback via cordova.exec method.. How can I get the return of success callback in `sample.html`.

Comment: Pass a callback function to your echo function and pass that to cordova.exec() instead of passing nativePluginResultHandler.

Comment: This is not a problem of delay, nor a problem of cordova, just the normal behaviour for javascript. Things are asynchronous, you can't expect the return value contain the response, you just can't.

Comment: But first it execute "alert("Return Value in login  :: " + value);" in simple.html then executing "alert("SUCCESS: \r\n" + result);" in simplejavaclass.js file.

Comment: so? what's the problem?

Comment: return getting delayed. is there any problem in thread web core thread or ui thread?

Comment: I gave you the answer about what's wrong with "your" code. Nothing is delayed (of course it takes time to call the echo on native side, this is not delaying, it's normal execution), your code is wrong. You should read/think about javascript. Good luck.